# Node MySQL Populate Children as an array

Tags: mysql, node.js, mysql2

I'm new to MySQL and coming from a Mongo background, so I'm used to Mongoose's .populate() method for retrieving a document's associations as a sub-array. Is there a way to do that in MySQL? Right now I'm trying to retrieve a single quiz with all of its questions in a single query. I have a `quizzes` table and a `questions` table, which has a `parent_quiz_id` field that refers to a quiz id. I've tried several permutations of `SELECT * FROM quizzes JOIN questions ON questions.parent_quiz_id = quizzes.quiz_id WHERE quizzes.quiz_id = ?` but they give me all the quiz information for each question, and that seems inefficient.

Is there a way for a single query to retrieve the quiz information once, and in subsequent rows populate all the questions that belong to that quiz?

This is what I'm doing now, with two separate queries:

connection.beginTransaction(function(err) {
                if (err) { throw err; }

```
            //First get the quiz data
            connection.execute('SELECT * FROM quizzes WHERE quiz_id = ? LIMIT 1', [id], function (err, quiz_results) {
                if (err) {
                    return connection.rollback(function() {
                        throw err;
                    });
                }

                const quiz = quiz_results[0];
                if(!quiz){
                    return done({ message: "No quiz found with that id"}, false);
                }

                //Now get all of the quiz's questions
                connection.execute('SELECT * FROM questions WHERE parent_quiz_id = ?', [id], function (err, question_results) {
                    if (err) {
                        return connection.rollback(function() {
                            throw err;
                        });
                    }

                    connection.commit(function(err) {
                        if (err) {
                            return connection.rollback(function() {
                                throw err;
                            });
                        }

                        quiz['questions'] = question_results;

                        return done(null, quiz);
                    });
                });
            });
        });
```

But I'd rather not use two separate queries. For references, I'm using Node MySQL2

Comment: Do you want to have a `quiz`, where the `questions` field is an array of the questions as a query result? I don't think this is possible with MySQL or any other RMDB sauf special extensions.
Maybe you don't need all the questions in a separate table, though? If I don't query individual questions, I often put them as a JSON in `questions` field of the `quizz`.

Comment: For this project, I unfortunately need questions as a separate table. But thanks for the suggestion!